# Transformar binário em um gráfico Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, matplotlib

Boa Noite tenho uma mensagem que transformei em binário e queria fazer um gráfico a partir dos seguintes padrões ami pseudoternário, onde caso seja o digito binário 1 a frequência fica em 0 e se o digito binário for 0 fica alternando a frequência entre positivo(1) e negativo(-1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando as bibliotecas tkinter e matplotlib mas estou aberto a outras opções. Minha tentativa foi percorrer cada digito da string binária e ir comparando se é 1 ou 0, porém estou com dificuldade mesmo de passar isso para o gráfico.

```
for i in binario.get():
    if i==1:
        #fazer algo no gráfico
    if i==0:
        #fazer algo no gráfico começando positivo e variar
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se você tem que aplicar alguma regra (você não chegou a especificar na pergunta e eu sinceramente não sei do que se trata este padrão), mas basicamente, se você quiser fazer o gráfico da imagem, basta usar o código abaixo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
binarios = [0,1,0,0,1,0]
graph = []
anterior = 0 # verifica se o numero anterior é 0, para pular para 1
index = [0]
i = 1 # precisa iniciar em 1 pq já temos a primeira posição no array de index
for binario in binarios:
    if(not binario): # not 0 -> true --> verifica se o binário é ZERO
        if(anterior == 0):
            graph.extend((1,1))
            anterior = 1
        else:
            graph.extend((-1,-1))
            anterior = 0
    else: # binário é HUM
        graph.extend((0,0))
    index.extend((i,i)) if i != len(binarios) else index.append(i)
    i += 1

plt.plot(index, graph)
```

Comment: ele especificou sim na pergunta que o padrão é [AMI bipolar invertido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_encoding). Eu upei um gráfico da sua função se quiser adicionar a resposta https://imgur.com/a/xwaFGVH

Comment: @AugustoVasques ISSO como eu faço?

Comment: @ErickNunes pegue esse código do Pedro Costa e cola no jupyter notebook que ele plota a função.